# Knowledge Articles Query Partner Community

Tags: lightning, knowledge, partner-communities, lightning-knowledge

I'm trying to query Knowledge Articles in our community, so I am not using standard layouts. (The query is in a lightning component.) But when I log in with a Partner Community Profile I get no articles visible. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

I am using Lightning Knowledge.

Some things I checked already:

- Sharing seems no option
- I can't give my user View All Permissions in the Profile to Knowledge-object
- My user has access to all Data Categories

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So stupid, you have to check the Partner Channel in the Knowledge Article as well. So this was the solution.